# Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3 - Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle

For a unknown reason Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3 is bugged and stopped to work, I updated gradle to `3.1-alpha03` and it stopped working, no matter if I download the project again, already downloaded Android Studio again too.

I've already checkout old versions of the project, but this message still show:

```
Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.getSelectedVariant()Lcom/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/model/ide/android/IdeVariant; (8s 806ms)
```

I've removed `.idea` folder, `.gradle` folder, did invalidate and restart

I don't know nothing more to do, cant run or use the IDE.

---

Edit:

[image]

---

Edit2:

New Projects doesnt work too

Comment: Can you try to do these steps (Clean project and sync project files):

1) Build > Clean Project from the menu bar.
2) Then sync your project files with Gradle by clicking 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' from the toolbar.

Comment: @TheLearner same error =\

Comment: This can be ignored, if you are using command prompt to compile your apk. I am having same error, but 'gradlew installDebug' works fine for me.

Comment: yep, only the ide is bugging

Comment: Uninstall kotlin plugin worked for me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a problem with Kotlin `1.1.60-release-Studio3.0-1` plugin.

Uninstall it from Android Studio and fetch an older version from here:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Comment: Yes, after installing older version (1.1.51-release-Studio3.0-1) the error is gone. I had to download in manually and install plugin from disk.

Comment: I was pulling my hair for couple of hours and this answer saved the day. Wondering what went wrong with the built in plugin.

Comment: After 4 hours got solution, Thank you for saving time.

Answer (score 22):

> To solve this issue, you have to either **upgrade or downgrade your kotlin plugin**

**Solution 1: Upgrade Plugin**

First go to Tools menu > Select Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates > Select one of the kotlin plugin & press download (stable or early access, i chose early access to solve this issue)

And finally change the kotlin version in build.gradle(Project:) according to the 
downloaded version

[image]

**Solution 2: Downgrade Plugin**

If your on **mac** then press: `Command + ,`
 to open preference, then select plugin & search for kotlin & uninstall it, it will rollback to previous version: 1.1.51

On **Windows machine**, press `Control + Alt + S` to open settings dialog, then select plugins & search for kotlin & uninstall it, it will rollback to previous version: 1.1.51

[image]

**Please Note:** Do not uncheck kotlin in plugins else it will disable kotlin & fail to recognise kotlin file & syntax

Comment: Better than the selected answer.

Comment: The first option worked for me.  After upgrading the Kotlin plugin, I was then asked to download a different version of Android build tools, but eventually the project sync succeeded.  What I don't understand is why this sort of problem happens all the time with Android Studio.  I have used Eclipse for many years, and it almost always works when upgrading to a new version.  I have used Android Studio a lot since it was first released, and rarely have I been able to open an existing project with a new version of Android Studio.  This kind of problem happens all the time with Android Studio.

Comment: I totally agree with you

Answer (score 6):

Try to [download](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?updateId=40489) and install [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/update/40489) kotlin plugin for android studio 3.1

Answer (score 2):

on Windows i just remove  from C:\Users\    folder -

.AndroidStudioPreview3.1

and all cache folders in .android ,.gradle too

and problem is gone)

Answer (score 2):

Faced same problem after upgrading to **Android Studio 3.1 stable**.

Kotlin plugin version was  ***1.2.30-release-Studio3.1-1***

So manually upgraded to,

> 1.2.31-release-Studio3.1-1

and boom, problem solved.

In short, try upgrading to most relevant plugin to fix gradle sync failure.

Comment: Also, It requires: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' in build.gradle files (app and project); min build tools version: buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' ; distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip in the gradle-wrapper.properties; And !important! uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.databinding:adapters:3.1.0] ...\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\adapters-3.1.0.aar\7631a24d9a29d78db9b47614fb87e2a8\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 9

Answer (score 1):

solved:

first run -> `find ~ -path ~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari -prune -o -iname \*android\*studio\* -print -prune`

DELETE ALL FOLDERS related to android-studio

start fresh install and project setup

Answer (score 1):

roll back  to the  previous  gradle version i have  faced  such issues  myself and  stay  away from RC gradle version unless  really  needed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading to:

```
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 10
Build #AI-181.2784.17.32.4705630, built on April 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b02 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.4
```

& `Kotlin plugin 1.2.31`

> I uninstalled the Kotlin plugin
>
> File | Invalidate Cache and restart
>
> Reinstalled the latest Kotlin plugin 1.2.31
>
> File | Invalidate Cache and restart

Everything is now okay.