# Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3 - Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-14

Using **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3** for Android application development using Kotlin, whenever the studio is opened, I get the following error

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g editing debugging) will not work properly

It is not the issue relevant to the built-in kotlin in Android studio version3.0 and above but the Kotlin plugin's

[image]

Comment: Well it could be one out of a 100 different things, what's the actual error?

Comment: Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.getSelectedVariant()Lcom/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/model/ide/android/IdeVariant; (6s 658ms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3 - Gradle sync failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290290/android-studio-3-1-canary-3-gradle-sync-failed)

Comment: Meaning, shouldn't be used 2 instances of android studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue that occurs when you import all the settings from your old version of Android Studio (where you would have already installed Kotlin in plugins) to Android Studio 3 and 3.1

So, to rectify the issue go to

***Preferences*** -> ***Plugins*** -> Search for ***Kotlin*** and ***Uninstall***

since we have built-in Kotlin support in the latest Android Studios, we may not need this Kotlin plugin anymore

Hope this helps!