# Android studio kotlin plugin error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

In android studio im getting an error:

```
Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught AbstractMethodError. Disable Plugin
```

Yesterday everything was fine.
Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Android studio version: 3.0.1 Build #AI-171.4443003

**Even more**: if i create new android project with kotlin support in fails with the same error.

**#EDIT1**

Full root gradle build script.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

1.1.60 does not help. Still same error. And still getting

```
Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51@jar' library is 1.1.51, while plugin version is 1.1.60-release-Studio3.0-1.
```

Even after updating to 1.1.60

Comment: add your whole build.gradle

Comment: What version is the plugin?

Comment: @Toolazy you got solution

Comment: yeah, posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught AbstractMethodError.

You should upgrade [**`kotlin_version`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html). Use **`1.1.60`** instead of **`1.1.51`**.

```
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
```

**NOTE**

**`1.1.60`** is **BUGGY**. Downgrade your Version.

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Gradle`**.

Comment: not helped. Getting message 'clean finished'. But in preview window 'waiting for build to finish'.

Comment: @TooLazy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290290/android-studio-3-1-canary-3-gradle-sync-failed

Answer (score 0):

As @IntelliJ Amiya mentioned downgrading kotlin plugin back to 1.1.51 did the trick.
1.1.60 buggy(